# Datanucleus 2.x and MySQL Bug #13955027 (SET OPTION)

Tags: mysql, exception, syntax, jdo, datanucleus

A MySQLSyntaxErrorException could occur when calling certain methods while connected to a MySQL 5.6.5 or higher server. Affected methods included StatementImpl.execute() and PreparedStatement.execute(). The cause was the removal of the SET OPTION syntax in the MySQL Server. The methods were modified to use the newer SET syntax internally. (Bug #13955027)

With DN 2.1 Release, i get this exception:

```
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:319)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1654)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1667)

NestedThrowablesStackTrace: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1051)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3563)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3495)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2687)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeSimpleNonQuery(StatementImpl.java:1544)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionImpl.java:3259)
at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.getTransactionIsolation(ConnectionHandle.java:621)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:478)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getXAResource(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:417)
at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.enlistResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:361)
at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:228)
at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:56)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:352)
at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getConnection(AbstractStoreManager.java:312)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.FetchRequest.execute(FetchRequest.java:290)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.fetchObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:319)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1928)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.validate(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:4414)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2785)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1649)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1667)
```

Is there a way to avoid this without upgrading DN libs?

Comment: why don't you post basic info like WHERE in the DN code there is use of "SET OPTION"? After all you presumably have some error, and some log entry, which corresponds to some line in the code yet don't present it (the top of some stack trace doesn't show anything useful ... what is below that... nested ...)

Comment: I posted the Nested Trace. If the problem is not in the JDBC driver (using latest version that addresses the bug), it can only be on datanucleus or boneCP. Going to investigate further. Thanks.

Comment: DN calls JDBC getConnection. The JDBC driver is then invoked. That is the only thing that can be issuing any such call. QED

Comment: You are right. I updated the DRIVER *but* my team did not use the more recent project update. The problem is NOT DN nor BoneCP. The problem was the MySQL JDBC Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, the solution is to upgrade to MySQL Connector/J 5.1.20 or later, which [includes the fix](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-1-20.html):

> A MySQLSyntaxErrorException could occur when calling certain methods
>   while connected to a MySQL 5.6.5 or higher server. Affected methods
>   included StatementImpl.execute() and PreparedStatement.execute(). The
>   cause was the removal of the SET OPTION syntax in the MySQL Server.
>   The methods were modified to use the newer SET syntax internally. (Bug
>   #13955027)